# Проблема с Float при отступе

Tags: html, css

[image: Макет]

Верстая макет,наткнулся на такую проблему:

Есть контейнер в контейнере есть блоки в две колонки,первый блок имеет верхний отступ,при этом все остальние блоки под ним выпадают из потока и  выравниваются  с новой строки.Как избежать выпадания блоков из потока и сделать выравнивание один за другим примерно как показано на скриншоте?

```css
.container{
  margin:  0 auto;
  font-size:  0;
  height:  100%;
  max-width:   300px;
  width:  100%;
}

.items{

  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.items:first-child{
  margin-top:  60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хотя бы  объясни, каков должен быть конечный результат?

Comment: @Air В конечном результате все блоки выравниваются ровно один за другим без непоятного оступа с низу

Comment: Один за другим по горизонтали или по вертикали?

Comment: @Air По вертикали,между блоками не должно бить никаких нижних  отступов

Comment: посмотри ответ.

Comment: @Air Я извиняюсь, но вы меня неправильно поняли, в вопросе добавил скриншот как все должно виглядить в конечном результате

Comment: я то тя правильно понял, это ты не правильно объяснил))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так работает поток документа.
Четвертый элемент не может вылезти из потока вверх (он как бы начинает с "новой строки").

Для информации: http://htmlbook.ru/blog/ponyatie-potoka

А что бы не мучиться с блочной версткой. Используйте современный Flex.

Если нужно что бы столбцы различались, то придется добавлять класс.

```css
.container{
  margin:  0 auto;
  font-size:  0;
  height:  100%;
  max-width:   300px;
  width:  100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}

.items{

  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
}

.items.left{
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items left"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items left"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items left"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
</div>
```

Либо как сделал @MedvedevDev с помощью `nth-child(2n-1)`:

```css
.container{
  margin:  0 auto;
  font-size:  0;
  height:  100%;
  max-width:   300px;
  width:  100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.items{
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
}

.items:nth-child(2n-1){
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Делал на Flexbox,такая же проблема,никак не получается убрать,нижний отступ  https://codepen.io/jSas/pen/OxrQjj

Comment: Не понимаю зачем вы делаете отступ только для первого элемента.
Если вам нужен отступ то и укажите его в контейнере.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NaeyyY

Comment: Таков дизайн макета

Comment: Немного доделал пен под (кажется) ожидаемый результат: [https://codepen.io/MedvedevDev/pen/EwGQdx](https://codepen.io/MedvedevDev/pen/EwGQdx)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.items {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  color: black;
}

.items:first-child {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">1</div>
  <div class="items">2</div>
  <div class="items">3</div>
  <div class="items">4</div>
  <div class="items">5</div>
  <div class="items">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: цифры добавил для себя что бы видно было положение блоков